# How do I save a UISlider value?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uislider

How could I save the value of a UISlider ?I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
-(IBAction)save {  
        slider1i = slider1.value;
        NSUserDefaults *slider1save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [slider1save setInteger:slider1i forKey:@"slider1key"];
        [slider1save synchronize];
}
```

`slider1i` is a NSinteger, and `slider1` is the UISlider ...

Can you help-me ?

Answer (score 1):

As user 698952 said, UISlider's [value](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006798-CH3-SW2) property is a float. But i'd instead use setFloat like this:

```
    slider1i = slider1.value;
    NSUserDefaults *slider1save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [slider1save setFloat:slider1i forKey:@"slider1key"];
    [slider1save synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

`slider1.value`is `float` value so you first need to convert it in NSString or NSNumber inorder to save it ..... that makes it a object

```
-(IBAction)save {  
        NSNumber *sliderValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:slider1.value];
        NSUserDefaults *slider1save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [slider1save setObject:sliderValue forKey:@"slider1key"];
        [slider1save synchronize];
}
```

thanks

Comment: did't work, every time I click to save look what happin: http://i53.tinypic.com/2qa3cyh.png

Comment: `setObject:`  not `setInteger:`. With setInteger you will save the address of the NSNumber object. Which is usually a very high number.

Comment: ya thats right.... replace line with [slider1save setValue:sliderValue forKey:@"slider1key"]; thanks @fluchtpunkt...